# Azure Data Warehouse SELECT n'char' Column Not Found

Tags: azure-synapse

Since ADW does not support multiple record inserts using the standard INSERT ... VALUES syntax, so the workaround is SELECT .. UNION ALL for each record.

For example:

```
-- this does work
INSERT INTO Banana.HamburgerTable (UnicodeColumn nvarchar(255)) 
VALUES (n'公');

-- this won't work
INSERT INTO Banana.HamburgerTable (UnicodeColumn nvarchar(255)) 
VALUES (n'公'),
(n'司') ;

-- this should work
INSERT INTO Banana.HamburgerTable 
SELECT n'公' UNION ALL
SELECT n'司';
```

However in practice the 2nd syntax returns this error:

`Failed to execute query. Error: Invalid column name 'n'.`

Why come?

Answer (score 0):

the unicode 'n' indicator at the beginning of the string is case sensitive in select statements,but case insensitive for insert values. So the correct version of the above statement is:

```
INSERT INTO Banana.HamburgerTable 
SELECT N'公' UNION ALL
SELECT N'司';
```